# Qt Creator. No debugger set up

Tags: qt, visual-studio

Здравствуйте. Установил Qt Creator 2.7.0. Нажимаю Debug, и вылезает ошибка: No debugger set up. Стоит VS 2012. Не подскажете как это исправить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для разработки/отладки в `Qt Creator 2.7.0` с использованием библиотек Qt для MSVS20**, нужно установить [CDB](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qtcreator/creator-debugger-engines.html).